# Running tests for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use RubyMine, Windows

I wrote test:

```
class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    # Replace this with your real tests.
    fixtures :posts
    test "the truth" do
        @first_posts = posts(:first_posts)
        assert @first_posts.title == "Ruby on rails"
    end
end
```

But when I run test with rubyMine ( with bottom button  I select "test" and run it)
i get this

```
C:\Ruby187\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\Ruby187\bin/rake test
Testing started at 1:44 PM ...
(in D:/Projects/TestProject)
Empty test suite.
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
Test suite finished: 0.031002 seconds
Errors running test:units!
Empty test suite.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

E.g my test suite is empty, but test suite has one test: "the truth"

When i run tests from console (ruby post_test.rb), I have

```
D:\Projects\TestProject\test>ruby unit/post_test.rb
Loaded suite unit/post_test
Started
Ruby on rails
.
Finished in 1.7471 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errorsWhat's wrong?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug RubyMine (build 98.47) http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-6158